# VS Plugin to highlight search term in Find Results pane (Find In Files)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in

I know there is such a plugin but I can't remember its name.

Anybody can help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Micorsoft's own [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) plugin for Visual studio has this function (amongst a lot of other very useful tools)

Comment: Thanks Edwin, this looks awesome but doesn't highlight the search terms in the results **pane**. Will keep it though, it's too good...

Comment: Yes, searching the search results was a not so obvious option for me but it does the trick though.